# Camera Intent doesn't returns data with every camera apps in device android

Tags: android

I am developing an app that takes photo through Cameras available in devices and returns image to the Imageview . This code does not works with every camera apps in device. For time being it only works with stock camera apps [ device -- Karbonn retina A27] , if used with other camera , the apps doesn't returns data OR apps hangs

CameraIntent.java

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
                View view=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_row,null);
                ImageView imgView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_image);                
                Bitmap bitmap=(Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
                byte bitObj[]=BirthdayCalculation.convertImageToByte(bitmap);
                Log.v("Photo byte.......", bitObj.toString());              
                ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
                values.put(BirthdayProvider.PHOTO, bitObj);
                int count=getContentResolver().update(BirthdayProvider.CONTENT_URI, values, BirthdayProvider.NUMBER+"='"+SearchListActivity.longClickValue+"'", null);
                if (count==1) {
                    finish();
                    imgView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 85, 80, false));
                    imgView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);                 
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Updated Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Updation Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }              
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. What is your question?

Comment: Its simple -- the code does't works with every camera apps in device

Comment: That is not a question. It is a statement.

Comment: Whatever u consider Sir --- pls provide me some solution .

Comment: Still problem not solved ---- help needed